# Why is my high-poly mesh bake result poor?

Tags: sculpting, texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I'm new to baking maps in general, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

I'm making some drumsticks, and I wanted them to appear used and "beat up", so I sculpted a lot of details into them. I'm trying to bake the highpoly into the lowpoly, but every time I try, the map has these vertical tears in it, and the map doesn't look good.

[image]

Am I adding *too* much detail? From what I understand, you have select your highpoly mesh first, then select the lowpoly - and as long as they're both in the same location in 3d space, you can bake it without issue. Is my understanding correct?

I'm new to sculpting as well, so I have no idea if how I sculpted it was good or bad. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

My .blend file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sh-CvePDW_XaNjJ4Ui4cL1WAFn1cGR4v/view?usp=sharing). It was too large to upload normally, which makes me feel like I'm doing something wrong already, haha.

EDIT:

Here's a screenshot of my normal map (I had to zoom in a little to show the artifacting)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your object is very small in your scene, so with an *Extrusion* of 0.5 it will miss the bake, bring back this value to 0, give a *Ray Distance* of 0.0001 and it will work.

[image]

Comment: Is the Extrusion setting in the Bake options?

Comment: Actually, I just tried it with the Ray Distance set to 0.0001, and it baked, but my normal map is quite sheared/torn vertically.. I'll update my main post and show you my normal map.

Comment: I can't say why it doesn't work, it works fine for me  :((

Comment: Do you think you can screenshot what the normal map looks like for you?

Comment: See my edit, I've recreated a 1024 x 1024 picture to make it quicker